# Tkinter update when combobox input exceeds 8

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

Basically, I'm trying to implement a feature where if the user enters input in the Combobox exceeding eight characters, it automatically creates a new combobox. I already have a button that makes a new combobox, I just need to figure out a way to call the function automatically when the user input exceeds eight digits.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


root = tk.Tk()
root.resizable(True, True)

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(sticky='nsew')
root.anchor("center")

#These are the buttons used for 
dropdown_barcode = []
quant_dropdown = []
delete_btn = []

canvas = tk.Canvas(frame)
canvas.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=(5, 0), sticky='nsew')

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=(5, 0), sticky='ns')

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

text_frame = tk.Frame(canvas)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=text_frame, anchor="nw")

def update_widgets():
    for id3, btn_widget in enumerate(delete_btn):
        btn_widget.grid(row=id3, column=0, pady=6, padx= (20,5))
    for idx, txt_widget in enumerate(dropdown_barcode):
        txt_widget.grid(row=idx, column=1, pady=6, padx=(5,5))
    for id2, quant_widget in enumerate(quant_dropdown):
        quant_widget.grid(row=id2, column=2, pady=6, padx=(5,0))

    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))


def new_item():
    new_bardcode = ttk.Combobox(text_frame, height=1, width=30, font=("Helvetica", 10))
    dropdown_barcode.append(new_bardcode)

    new_quant = ttk.Combobox(text_frame, height=1, width=5, font=("Helvetica", 10))
    quant_dropdown.append(new_quant)

    # Get the index of the current row
    current_index = len(dropdown_barcode) - 1
    delete_btn1 = tk.Button(text_frame, text="-", width= 3, command=lambda idx=current_index: remove_item(idx))
    delete_btn.append(delete_btn1)

    update_widgets()


def remove_item(index):
    # Destroy widgets related to the index
    dropdown_barcode[index].destroy()
    quant_dropdown[index].destroy()
    delete_btn[index].destroy()

    # Remove them from the lists
    del dropdown_barcode[index]
    del quant_dropdown[index]
    del delete_btn[index]

    update_widgets()

send_item = tk.Button(frame, text="->")
add_txtbox = tk.Button(frame, text="+", command=new_item)
remove_text_btn = tk.Button(frame, text="-", command=remove_item)
employee_id= ttk.Combobox(frame, height=1, width=30, font=("Helvetica", 10))


add_txtbox.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=(0, 250), pady=10)
send_item.grid(row=3, column=0, pady=6, padx=(280, 0))
employee_id.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=(15,0))

new_item()  # Add the initial text widget

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perhaps you could use the validatecommand option to specify a callback function that checks on the input key (validate='key') whether the input is more than 8 characters and if so creates a new combobox

Comment: Alternatively to @telina's suggestion, you could `bind` a callback to `'<Key>'` for each `Combobox` and have it check the length of the input. That's likely easier to implement, but perhaps not as robust as using `validatecommand`

Comment: What happens when the length of input changes from 8 to 7, then 7 to 8, etc?

Comment: But from what I've seen online, there are only pre-defined keys such as "left mouse click" and the "enter button". How do I make a custom key?

Comment: @acw1668 The user wont be able to delete characters, they can just add.

Comment: @dqdqdqsss How do you prevent user from deleting input in the entry box of the combobox?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify my comment. You could use the `validatecommand` option to hook a callback function whenever the user enters a `key`. You do not need to specify that key. You can use the [substitution codes](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/entry-validation.html) to further specify the value that shall be passed to the hooked function.

A simple way to achieve this with your code:

Modify the function new_item() such that:

```
new_bardcode = ttk.Combobox(text_frame, height=1, width=30, font=("Helvetica", 10), validate='key', validatecommand=(root.register(onValidateComboBoxEntry), '%P'))
```

and the matching callback function:

```
def on_validate_combobox_entry(text):
    if (len(text) > 8):
        new_item()
    return True
```

This will simply create a new combobox whenever there is more than 8 characters provided in the initial one (and further added ones). So you would have to somehow freeze the existing if you do not want to be able to enter more.
I hope this goes into the direction of what you were asking for.

Answer (score -1):

The way I would solve this is to associate the widget with a variable, then put a trace on the variable to trigger the new role when you insert more than 8 characters.

I would do this by creating a custom combobox class that emits an event when the widget is edited. You can then bind to this event to call a callback.

Here's what the class might look like:

```
class CustomCombobox(ttk.Combobox):
    """ttk.Combobox that emits a <<ComboboxEdited>> event"""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        var = self.cget("textvariable")
        self._var = self.getvar(var) if var else tk.StringVar(master=self)
        if not var:
            self.configure(textvariable=self._var)
        self._var.trace_add("write", self._callback)

    def _callback(self, *args):
        self.event_generate("<<ComboboxEdited>>")
```

You can then create a callback and bind to that callback. The callback might look like this:

```
def maybe_add_combobox(event):
    value = event.widget.get()
    if len(value) > 8:
        new_item()
```

You can then use this custom class to create your comboboxes and bind to the event:

```
def new_item():
    new_bardcode = CustomCombobox(text_frame, height=1, width=10, font=("Helvetica", 10))
    new_bardcode.bind("<<ComboboxEdited>>", maybe_add_combobox)
    ...
```